# Android studio: How to auto-generate views variables from xml to java class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following activity xml file:

[image]

I would like to generate all the views variables in the java file base on their name.

For this example:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText_firstname;
    private TextView label_lastname;
    // .. So on

    private void setup_views() {
         editText_firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_firstname);
         label_lastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_lastname);
         // .. So on
    }
}
```

It very frustrating to do it all over again for any new activity, and I seems to basic to not be in android studio.

So, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in java for did not develop`findviewByid()` you can use dataBinding library like [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

or use android native [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding as mentioned above or switch to Kotlin and you won't need `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

In java it may be frustating but if you switch to Kotlin it will be much easier to draw a lyaout using this great [Anko Library](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has a plugin which allows you to do that, please refer the below link to get the plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7595-android-code-generator

Answer (score 0):

In the recent release of Android API, [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) is the recommended way to manipulate view components.

However, if you really need the classic findViewById(), here are several plugins that you can use in Android Studio:

1. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11204-android-findviewbyid-support
2. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7595-android-code-generator
3. https://github.com/laobie/FindViewByMe
4. https://github.com/dotnet-ad/AutoFindViews